# How can maintain ordering sequencing order while convert all key and value of dictionary into array

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have on dictionary response as below

```
 responceDict=  {
 "2012-11-01" = 46700;
 "2012-11-02" = 27400;
 "2012-11-03" = 19400;
 "2012-11-04" = 15100;
}
```

I want to get both values in two array like

```
 arrayDate=[2012-11-01,2012-11-02,2012-11-03,2012-11-04]
 arrayVal=[46700,27400,19400,15100];
```

I have used

```
 arrayDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 arrayVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (id obj in responceDict.allKeys ) {
       // NSLog(@"%@  %@",obj,[responceArr valueForKey:obj]);
        [arrWaterReport addObject:obj];
        [arrDischarge addObject:[responceArr valueForKey:obj]];
    }
```

But in this i can't maintain date sequence by its sorting order.

So would any one suggest me how can i maintain it's sequencing order.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` is unsorted. It's a hash table, not an ordered list. You'll need to do your ordering after you've moved your items to an `NS[Mutable]Array`.

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution for this

```
 for (id obj in [[responceDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)])
    {
        [arrayDate addObject:obj];
        [arrValue addObject:[responceDict valueForKey:obj]];
    }
```

Thanks